# Is it possible to pass a WebBrowser as argument to another form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference, parameter-passing, webbrowser-control

I am developing an application in VB.NET wherein I have an WebBrowser control in my Main window Form named say "Form1".

Form1 as several tabs and among them the first tab is for the webbrowser control named "wb1". As the window is opened some url say "abc.com" is getting loaded.

This abc.com website has some log in option and after log in manually into the website user gets work one by one after resolving them one by one (FIFO).

Every work rather I should say webpage has several frames. Now what I want is, if user clicks on a button another form say "Form2" will appear which will have a webbrowser control named say "wb2".

I want to replicate the current wb1 instance into wb2. Is it possible to pass it as argument or in any other way?

In case if you misunderstand my query or requirement, please feel free to comment, I would explain again. Thanks all. Waiting for a solution.

Comment: if you want the same instance in Form2 you can just pass the web browser control to that form. Note: whatever changes you make in Form2 will be reflected in Form1 also.

Comment: Have you tried, Passing it as argument?

Comment: You wouldn't pass the `WebBrowser` control as an argument. You would get from the `WebBrowser` whatever information was required and then pass that. the second form would then use that information to configure its own `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily pass a reference to a webbrowser control to another form.

In Form2 you define a method like this

```
Public Sub DoSomethingWithWebBrowser(wb as WebBrowser)
    wb.DoWhatever
End Sub
```

Then in Form1 just call this method passing the name of the control:

```
Form2.DoSomethingWithWebBrowser(WebBrowser1)
```